# ES how to refactor a querying with a join like?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've created 2 queries in elastic search:

```
 GET poc-2020.01.09/_search
{   
 "size": 1000,
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
        "message": {
            "value": "got*",                         <-------------
            "boost": 1.0,
            "rewrite": "constant_score"
        }
    }
}
```

}

returns:

```
   {
    "_index": "poc-2020.01.09",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "YicNiG8BsW6Znkt6BLuc",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "offset": 618993630,
      "node.tag": "taskmanager",
      "logfile.name": "app-taskmanager-1-94hhg.log",
      "logtype": "app",
      "beat": {
        "version": "6.3.2",
        "hostname": "infra",
        "name": "infra"
      },
      "@version": "1",
      "type": "beats",
      "tags": [
        "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
      ],
      "@timestamp": "2020-01-09T02:05:51.251Z",
      "source": "/nfsdata/ecs/log/app-taskmanager-1-94hhg.log",
      "message": """2020-01-09 02:04:39,825 INFO  Utils - got OOO: XYZ:912828YZ7 Metrics:[] """,
      "app.tag": "flink-app-treasury-enriched-position",
      "env": "DEV",
      "host": {
        "name": "infra-elkagent-29-xhx2x"
      }
    }
  },
```

**(it's returns got OOO messages in this example: with XYZ:912828YZ7)**

And querying

```
 GET gsp.datasphere.flink.poc-2020.01.09/_search
 {
 "size": 10,
 "query": {
    "wildcard": {
        "message": {
            "value": "outputing*",
            "boost": 1.0,
            "rewrite": "constant_score"
        }
    }
}
```

}

returns:

```
"hits": {
"total": 104605,
"max_score": 1,
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "poc-2020.01.09",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "3wfYh28BsW6Znkt67Sho",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "offset": 617979882,
      "node.tag": "taskmanager",
      "logfile.name": "app-taskmanager-1-94hhg.log",
      "logtype": "app",
      "beat": {
        "version": "6.3.2",
        "hostname": "infra-elkagent-29-xhx2x",
        "name": "infra-elkagent-29-xhx2x"
      },
      "@version": "1",
      "type": "beats",
      "tags": [
        "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
      ],
      "@timestamp": "2020-01-09T01:08:56.220Z",
      "source": "/nfsdata/ecs/log/app-taskmanager-1-94hhg.log",
      "message": "2020-01-09 01:07:34,011 INFO  Function  - Outputing gotoSchool: XYZ:912828YZ7",
      "app.tag": "app-trx",
      "env": "DEV",
      "host": {
        "name": "infra"
      }
    }
  },
```

**(it's returns got gotoSchool messages in this example: with :XYZ:912828YZ7)**

please note that for each gotoSchool message there are many OOO messages.

what i really need is a query that can join between them. (by the value - XYZ:912828YZ7 - the number after the "XYZ:" is the join value.

(so for each parent to return itself with it's childs).

can you assist?

thanks.

Comment: It is possible to extract the value after XYZ and store it in a new field ? (could make aggregation on it after, joining source)

Comment: i cannot change the data (update it etc)